# Can't find or load main class

Tags: java

For some reason I am getting an error saying that it can not find or load my main class, can anyone give me a reason for this?

```
package FindFile;

import java.io.File;

/**
 *
 * @author Kevin
 */
public class FindFile
{
    public void listFilesAndFolders(String directoryName)
    {
        File directory = new File(directoryName);       
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

        for (File file : fList)
        {
            System.out.println(file.getName());
        }
    }

    public void listFiles(String directoryName)
    {
        File directory = new File(directoryName);
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

        for (File file : fList)
        {
            if (file.isFile())
            {
                System.out.println(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    public void listFolders(String directoryName)
    {
        File directory = new File(directoryName);
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

        for(File file : fList)
        {
            if (file.isDirectory())
            {
                System.out.println(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    public void listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(String directoryName)
    {
        File directory = new File(directoryName);
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

        for (File file : fList)
        {
            if (file.isFile())
            {
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            } else if (file.isDirectory())
            {
                listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FindFile findFile = new FindFile();
        final String directoryWindows = "C:\\test";

        findFile.listFiles(directoryWindows);

    }
}
```

Comment: looks ok to me. Are you using an IDE or cmd line? If IDS can you right click on the file and try and run it as an application?

Comment: An error from where, how, when, etc. Please add useful information so we can answer your question.

Comment: When i run this program in Textpad the following shows up        

"Error: Could not find or load main class FindFile.FindFile" (without the quotes)

Comment: "Could not find..." issues tend to be the result of naming/directory structure/path problems. Is the file itself actually named FindFile.java? Is everything in the place it is expected to be, and on a PATH that can be found? Since (according to your comment on RB-Develop's answer) you're using NetBeans, what happens if you press Shift-F6 (run file)?

Answer (score 3):

Your class is fine, I think your "IDE" (Textpad ?) does not seem to manage compilation and running of java programs.

just look at the location where the compiler writes the class file, this should be something like:

```
FindFile/FindFile.class
```

Just go to the directory where the directory `FindFile` is, open a command line window and run your class like this:

```
java FindFile.FindFile
```

I suggest you to use a real [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) for instance is a good one for java developing.

Comment: Aah, beat me to it. I was going to add that chances are that your class file is not residing in FindFile/FindFile.class. Your package name has to be identical to the folder name that the class resides in.

Comment: @NileshTailor the java compiler automatically generates the directories specified by the package declaration if passed the option `-d <output_dir>` otherwise the `.class` file is generated in the same location as the `.java` file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be your project set-up. If you are using an IDE like NetBeans or Eclipse you can define what .java file holds the main function for execution. If that is not set-up it will tell you there is no main function. What Nilesh Tailor tells you might as well be the problem, I haven't worked with Java for some time and I can't fully remember the function constraints regarding class definitions.

Comment: where do I go in netbeans to find this?

Comment: if you use NetBeans: right click on the project -> properties -> 'Run' tab -> Main class. It has a text box and a button to the right of it. Click on the button and it should show you a list of all the .java files in your project containing a valid main function. If it doesn't show a file it means your code is wrong.